# How to populate value of an iframe input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, iframe

I have a jsp page, and inside it an iframe, within a form, written like this:

```
<body onload="onloadFunction();">
    <form method="post" target="frameWindow" action="http://iframelink.com" id="businessProcessForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("username") %>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" value="<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("passwordReceived") %>" />
    <iframe name="frameWindow" class="businessProcessFrame" id="frameWindow"></iframe>
    </form>
</body>
```

The js code for the body onload function is this:

```
function onloadBusinessProcess7() {
   document.getElementById('businessProcessForm').submit();
}
```

So what i wanted to do is to take the values from the hidden fields, populate the fields from the iframe page (which also has a form inside it) and hit submit from jquery.

The code I wrote for that is this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#frameWindow").load(function () {
            $('#frameWindow').contents()
                             .find('#j_username').val('myValue');
            alert("usernameValue = " +
                  $('#frameWindow').contents().find('#j_username').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sadly, this doesn't work at all, I tried a lot of ways to populate those fields but I couldn't find anything that works.

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you won't be able to do this due to same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @vasil, that depends on whether or not the iframe content is from the same domain as the surrounding document.

Comment: _“So what i wanted to do is to take the values from the hidden fields, populate the fields from the iframe page (which also has a form inside it) and hit submit from jquery.”_ – so the values should be input in the “main” page, then transferred into the form inside the iframe, and then that form inside the iframe be submitted? Maybe instead you can just submit your main page form _into_ the iframe directly, by giving it a `target` attribute? (That of course will only work if the iframe form has no additional fields that have to be send with it.)

Comment: @CBroe yes, that is exactly what I have to do.. Initially, I just wanted to see that those fields are populated inside the iframe, so I could see that it may work.

Comment: Well the (implicit) question whether or not the document inside the iframe is from the same domain or not is still unanswered – so …?

Comment: No, it is not from the same domain.. is that a big problem for the jquery to be able to populate those fields?

Comment: @CBroe I know that it depends, but most commonly iframe is used when the content is not from the same domain. There are much much much cleaner solutions in cases where the content is on the same domain.

Comment: _“is that a big problem for the jquery to be able to populate those fields?”_ – it’s what makes this _impossible_; see link that Vasil already posted in the first comment.